# safari and iphone issue with -webkit-box-shadow

Tags: safari, css

I have an unordered list which is set to display block. Inside that UL I have 4 li elements which are floating.

There is an issue when displaying it in Safari and therefore on iphone and ipad. The issue is that the inner element is inset slightly by the shadow:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

but it displays fine in Chrome

[image: Safari screenshot]

Any ideas??

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem CAN be as follow..

You probably don't saw it coming but do you use a border radius?
The chrome version has 1 pixxel padding on the top/left/right side which can output differently on your screen..

underneath can be helpful if you use a browser reset in your stylesheet

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html

This will reset all browsers to the same index and from there start styling and mostly it will  work!